# How to receive parameters send via HttpParams

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a angular6 project. Using form angular services I call the API and send a parameter in the following way:

**Angular 6**

```
GetUserList() {

var paramsT = new HttpParams();
paramsT.append('userID', '100');
paramsT.append('name', 'himadri');

return this.http.get(this.baseURLApi + "/User/GetUserList", { params: paramsT });
 }
```

How can I receive the parameters sent by HttpParams in asp.net core MVC web API? In have tried the following, but it did not work.

**.NetCore Web Api**

```
 public JsonResult GetUserList([FromQuery] string userID, [FromQuery] string name)
    {
        ClsUser u = new ClsUser();
        return Json(u.GetUserListDB().ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: What you get in your network tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send a request as below :

```
/User/GetUserList?userID=100&name=himadri
```

However, what actually sent by the client is :

```
/User/GetUserList?
```

The reason is that your `paramsT` is an brand new `HttpParams`.Note the `append(string,string)`  will return a new body with an appended value for the given parameter name. So you need change your code to be :

```
var paramsT = new HttpParams()
    .append('userID', '100')
    .append('name', 'himadri');
```

And now the requested URL and querystring will be correct .

See [docs here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

Comment: @himadri Try and get into the habit of upvoting answers as well as accepting them. It gives the answerer a few more internet points. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) is immutable, and `append` method return a new `HttpParams`
Your code should be:

```
GetUserList() {
    let paramsT = new HttpParams();
    paramsT = paramsT.append('userID', '100');
    paramsT = paramsT.append('name', 'himadri');

    return this.http.get(this.baseURLApi + "/User/GetUserList", { params: paramsT });
}
```

or

```
GetUserList() {

    const paramsT = new HttpParams()
        .append('userID', '100')
        .append('name', 'himadri');

    return this.http.get(this.baseURLApi + "/User/GetUserList", { params: paramsT });
}
```